# SQL: Finding min, max date with repeated value

Tags: sql, azure, azure-databricks

If I have data like below and I need to find min and max date of each promotion order by date
Please help me for SQL script

**Data:**
[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiXr0.png)

```
Data:   
month           promotion
31/01/2019          A
28/02/2019          A
31/03/2019          B
30/04/2019          C
31/05/2019          C
30/06/2019          C
31/07/2019          C
31/08/2019          C
30/09/2019          B
31/10/2019          B
30/11/2019          B
31/12/2019          B
```

**need result:**
[Need result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgtA8.png)

```
need result:        
min_month   max_month   promotion
31/01/2019  28/02/2019  A
31/03/2019  31/03/2019  B
30/04/2019  31/08/2019  C
30/09/2019  31/12/2019  B
```

**result i got: incorrect**
[result i got: incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpKqT.png)

```
min_month   max_month   promotion
31/01/2019  28/02/2019  A
31/03/2019  31/12/2019  B
30/04/2019  31/08/2019  C
```

Thank you

My script

```
select promotion, min(month) min_month, max(month) max_month  
from table  
group by promotion
```

Comment: you'll need to provide your SQL query so we can debug it

Comment: why do you get B twice for promotion

Comment: Plesse tag your DBMS product.

Comment: @VenkataramanR Because some customer get same promotion in different period, so I'd like to know how long they held each promotion.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is form of GAPS and ISLAND problem. If your DBMS supports window functions, You may try below query -

```
select min(month) min_month, max(month) max_month, promotion
from (select promotion,
             month,
             rank() over(order by month) seqnum1,
             rank() over(partition by promotion order by month) seqnum2
      from table) t
group by promotion, seqnum1 - seqnum2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `lag()` to fill the gap :

```
select promotion, min(month) as min_month, max(month) as max_month
from (select t.*, 
             sum(case when promotion <> prev then 1 else 0 end) over (order by month) as grp
      from (select t.*, 
                   lag(promotion) over (order by month) as prev
            from table t
           ) t
     ) t
group by promotion, grp
order by min(month);
```